# Event handling difference between declarations?

Tags: c#, events, lambda

I'm trying to understand the difference between:

```
someObject.SomeEventName += OnEventHappend;

private void OnEventHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

AND

```
someOBject.SomeEventName += ( o, e) => { };
```

Is there a difference and does it matter one way or the other.

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, that second method freaks me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is called a "lambda".  It's a way of creating an anonymous function.

Other than the fact that the second function doesn't have a name, and thus can't be used anywhere else, while the first does have a name and *could* be used somewhere else, there aren't really any differences.

The compiler will end up creating a class and a method within that class to represent the lambda, so technically it will have a name, you just won't be allowed to use it in your code.

Probably the most significant point to note is that lambdas can close over variables.  This is where the lambda body refers to a varaiable outside of it's own scope, i.e:

```
int value = 5;

someObject.SomeEvent += (s,e) => { Console.WriteLine(value);};
```

The same functionality can be accomplished using entirely named methods (after all the compiler will refactor that code into named methods/objects at some point) but the end result will be slightly more complex than just one new method in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Well one obvious difference is that the later is an anonymous event handler implemented as a statment lambda, so you can't easily unsubscribe it at a later date. The advantage of it though is its succinctness.